.NET 8 ISOLATED upgrade stopped logging Infomation, Debug
I recently upgraded our Azure Functions app from .NET 6 (in-progress model) to .NET 8 (isolated worker model). Some strange behavior is occuring where I'm unable to see Information (or below) level logs. The settings pertaining to logs are the same; everything worked in .NET 6. I'm trying to see these logs locally in my console.
Code:
Logger?.LogError("Test if we can log error");
Logger?.LogWarning("Test if we can log warning");
Logger?.LogInformation("Test if we can log info");
Logger?.LogDebug("Test if we can log debug");

Logs:
[2024-05-30T10:24:45.823Z] Test if we can log error
[2024-05-30T10:24:45.824Z] Test if we can log warning
.. that's it

Logging obviously works because I can see Error and Warning log levels. My host.json:
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "AlarmFunctions.Functions": "Debug",
      "DataLayer": "Debug",
      "ServiceLayer": "Debug",
      "Function": "Warning",
      "default": "Warning"
    },
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Trace;Request"
      },
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
    }
  }
}

Important to note is that logLevel in host.json does not apply anymore. Above provided logging code is located in namespace AlarmFunctions.Functions.SomeClassName but changing loglevel to "AlarmFunctions.Functions": "Error" still makes the warning log show up.
I tried changing ApplicationInsights log level as well but it doesn't change anything. I also tried this but it doesn't work either.
Am i missing something?
Thanks

As you write, specifying log levels in host.json doesn't apply to functions. The log levels in host.json apply to the host process for the runtime but not the process actually executing the function.

@ThomasArdal thanks for the reply. It worked in .NET 6 that way though. Can you please tell me how i can specify log levels for the function then?

You can create appsettings like you would do for ASP.NET Core or a console app. Check out the log filtering section here: https://docs.elmah.io/logging-to-elmah-io-from-isolated-azure-functions/#log-filtering (just ignore the content about elmah.io, the description is valid for any logger)

@ThomasArdal thanks again but i tried everything in that example and my logs still aren't showing up below warning. The only way i can make them show up is if i turn Function to Debug in host.json

Can you post the relevant parts of your Program.cs so we can see how you're setting up logging? I think the mechanism changed with the intro of isolated, like how @ThomasArdal said.

If you are looking to set log levels specific to Functions. You need to add filter in Program.cs file.
My Function:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FunctionApp12
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;
        public Function1 (ILogger<Function1> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }
        [Function("Function1")]
        public IActionResult Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req)
        {
            _logger?.LogCritical("Critical log");
            _logger?.LogWarning("Warning log");
            _logger?.LogError("Error Log");
            _logger?.LogInformation("Information log");

            var responseMessage = "Welcome to Azure Functions";

           return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
        }
    }
}


FunctionApp12.csproj:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.17.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.3.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.2.0" />  
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

Program.cs:
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
    })
    .ConfigureLogging((context, logging) =>
    {
       logging.AddFilter("FunctionApp12.Function1", LogLevel.Warning);
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();

host.json:
{
    "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Debug"
    },
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      },
      "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
    }
  }
}

OUTPUT:



Thanks for the response. Is there any way that you know of to make it so that i see ONLY my own custom logs? So not the rest of the blue/green that you see in the console there?

@Kars these green and blue logs are debug logs. which is set in "default": "Debug" in host.json. you can set it at higher level if you do not want to see lower level logs.

Using "default": "Warning" this is how it is all other logs are removed image

But that will also remove my personal LogDebug lines, and i need to see those.

@Kars Yes. Lowest level Log level can be set is function level.

So is there a way to see only my own logs and not those annoying other ones?

@Kars if you want to see only your debug level log from your function we can set "default": "Warning" "Function.<function name>": "Debug". image

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
